# Will pywin32 extensions work on Windows 7?

Tags: python, windows-7

Will the [pywin32 extensions](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/) work on Windows 7?

If not, are there plans for Windows 7 extensions for Python?

Answer (score 1):

pywin32 extensions works fine on Windows 7.